# Java - classpath: Is it necessary to add "$CLASSPATH:" as prefix in "-cp"

Tags: java, classpath

*(For, simplicity, the question assumes working on **linux**)*

When install java, I usually set `CLASSPATH` environment variable for java, it include current path & some jar from jdk/jre. e.g:

`.:/mnt/star/program/java/jdk1.8.0_11/lib/tools.jar:/mnt/star/program/java/jdk1.8.0_11/lib/dt.jar`

In java command `java` and `javac`, we might need specify classpath by `-cp`.

And I always use `$CLASSPATH:` as prefix, when specify `-cp`.

**My question is:** Is the prefix necessary?

Comment: You shouldn't define any CLASSPATH variable at all. Let each program have its own classpath, distinct from other programs.

Comment: You don't need to add the JDK jars, first of all. Secondly, you need it if you have stuff in it you need for *all* your programs, but as JB states, it's better to not use it at all, and set each program's classpath some other way, like by a shell script, an all-in-one had, etc.

Comment: Ok, I will remove the CLASSPATH in future, thanks.